# Remapping the keyboad

Tags: keyboard, xkb, remapping

Ubuntu 18.04 LTE

I am trying to Remap the Right alt key with the 'down' key and the Backslash key with the the 'right' key. I've modified the 'pc' file in the xkb directory, restarted, but I did not see the remapping in effect. Can somebody Suggest me a way to permanently remap these keys?

Comment: can you run  `xev` commad and press each key once and note down the keycode and keysym values for the 4 keys you mentioned. Ingeneral it is possible with `xmodmap`

Comment: I would not recommend trying to modify a modifier key's keysym mapping. You may end up with weird side effects. I'd remap the key's scancode to a different keycode instead.

Comment: hi @danzel.. is there differnce between keycode and scan code?

Comment: @PRATAP the scancode is what the keyboard sends to the kernel and has no meaning at first. It is then mapped to a keycode which is an abstract representation of a key on a typical 105 key keyboard (e.g. `KEY_UP`,`KEY_Y`). The keycode is then mapped to keysyms by `xkb` depending on the keycode and modifier keys currently pressed. Both keycode and keysym are reported to applications. The problem with remapping keycode>keysym is that some applications only check the keycode and ignore the (remapped) keysym, which is especially the case with modifier keys.

Comment: @danzel, I see.. but I several times remaped with the modifier keys but did not observe any difficulty in day to day work.. thanks for the inf0..

Comment: keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down)-->keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R),keycode 51 (keysym 0x5c, backslash)-->keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right)
 [the key to be modified]-->[the resulting key]

Comment: 0k..creatae a file named  `.xmodmaprc` in your home folder and put `keycode 116 = Alt_R` `keycode 114 = backslash` in two lines.. and then run `xmodmap .xmodmaprc` to make this change to effective instantly..

Comment: when ever you wish to revert the changes.. just delete the file  `.xmodmaprc`

Comment: ok thanks, but how to make the changes permanent, the remapping just reset after I reboot

Comment: just keep this command in startup applications `xmodmap .xmodmaprc`